# Where is GNU info files stored on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, command-line

For example, where could I find the [info document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) of bash on mac OSX. I only know the man page is stored at `/usr/share/man/` but doesn't know where to find the info file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the following locations:

`/usr/share/info/`

`/usr/local/share/info/`